# One liner for cartesian of two vectors with colnames set and stringsAsFactors = FALSE in R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, data.table, cartesian-product

I'd like to do a cartesian of two vectors in R that

1. Returns `data.frame` with column names
2. Returns character columns instead of factors

I can certainly do this in a few lines of code.

```
df <- merge(1:3, letters[1:3], all = TRUE)
colnames(df) <- c("number", "letter")
df$letter <- as.character(df$letter)
str(df)
## 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ number: int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
##  $ letter: chr  "a" "a" "a" "b" ...
```

But ideally, this would be a one-liner such as the code below (that does not produce the desired output).

```
df2 <- merge(c(number = 1:3),
             c(letter = letters[1:3]), all = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df2)
## 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ x: int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
##  $ y: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Anyone have one-liners that could work on this reprex?  Happy to also entertain `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions.  Ideal solution would show provide a one-liner for each `base`, `dplyr`, and `data.table`.

Comment: Check what `c(number = 1:3)` returns. It's not what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone's answers here are great. Just to add to them, `tidyr` has a `crossing` function that would suit your need as well.

```
> tidyr::crossing(numbers = 1:3, letters = letters[1:3])
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  numbers letters
    <int> <chr>  
1       1 a      
2       1 b      
3       1 c      
4       2 a      
5       2 b      
6       2 c      
7       3 a      
8       3 b      
9       3 c
```

Answer (score 5):

`help("merge")` says

> Arguments
>
> x, y   data frames, or objects to be coerced to one.

This hints at the solution:

```
df2 <- merge(data.frame(number = 1:3),
             data.frame(letter = letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE), all = TRUE)
str(df2)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ number: int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
# $ letter: chr  "a" "a" "a" "b" ...
```

Answer (score 4):

`expand.grid` is commonly used in cases like this. It generalizes up nicely, use `do.call` to use it on a `list` of vectors to expand.

```
res = expand.grid(
   numbers = 1:3,
   letters = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(res)
#   numbers letters
# 1       1       a
# 2       2       a
# 3       3       a
# 4       1       b
# 5       2       b
# 6       3       b

str(res)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ numbers: int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
#  $ letters: chr  "a" "a" "a" "b" ...
#  - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
#   ..$ dim     : Named int  3 3
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "numbers" "letters"
#   ..$ dimnames:List of 2
#   .. ..$ numbers: chr  "numbers=1" "numbers=2" "numbers=3"
#   .. ..$ letters: chr  "letters=a" "letters=b" "letters=c"
```